# using jquery and kohana

Tags: jquery, json

well I havn't really ever using jquery to grab data from a server.. and well my jquery skills are pretty limited anyway so maybe im doing the jquery wrong ...im not sure

heres my controller to handle the json requests

```
class Controller_Json extends Controller_Template{

public function get_chat_entries(){
    echo json_encode($this->db->get('chat_entries')->result());
}}
```

and heres my view that is meant to test it

```
<ul id="chats">

</ul>
<script>
   $.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
     $('#chats').html('<li>' + data.text + '</li>');
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code in my test base kohana. your js code is ok.
problem is **mysql_resoure to json conversion**. 
i.e. `"echo json_encode($this->db->get('chat_entries')->result());"` 
result method returns mysql_resoure which needs to be converted into array.

it works when if i put like this 
...

```
echo json_encode($this->db->get('emails')->current());
```

...
only one email is displayed inside of #chats ul list.

PS: emails is my table contains multiple email address

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell cause you don't provide any details about the error itself but I'd guess this might solve your problem:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#95667

> If you are planning on using this function to serve a json file, it's important to note that the json generated by this function is not ready to be consumed by javascript until you wrap it in parens and add ";" to the end.

Cheers,
aefxx

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing out on the document ready wrapper. I would wrap my jquery code inside a document.ready method like this :`

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
         $('#chats').html('<li>' + data.text + '</li>');
     });
   }); 
</script>
```

I would also test the 'ajax/test.json' url from my browser to check if the server is returning a proper json string. Also make sure that the data object obtained inside your ajax callback function has a text property.

Comment: thanks this helped aswell... stupid me needs to learn how to try simple troubleshooting methods